# Does a real number being less than the supremum of a set imply it is contained in the set?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Consider a set $X$ such that $X$ does not have a lower bound, and it has a supremum $C = \sup X$. If I have some $a \in \mathbb{R}$, does $a < C$ mean that $a \in X$?

I understand that since $C$ is an upper bound, we have $x \leq C$ for all $x \in X$, but does the fact that $C$ is the 'smallest upper bound' imply that the above is true?

Edit: $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, my apologies for forgetting.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Is $X$ a set of real numbers?

Comment: Let $X$ be the real numbers $s$ with the properties $s<1$ and $s\ne 0$. Then , we have $sup(X)=1$ , but $0$ is not in $X$ , although $0<1$ and $X$ has no lower bound.

Comment: Have you tried thinking of examples of such sets? If you do, you should quickly see that this is not true.

Comment: A good exercise for OP might be to try to think of an additional condition on $X$ that will make the statement true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no (considering of course that $X\subset\mathbb{R}$). Here is a counter-example : let $X=\mathbb{Z}^-$, the set of all negative integers. Its supremum is $C=-1$, there is of course no lower bound. But you can see that $-1.5<C$ but obviously $-1.5\notin\mathbb{Z}^-$.

Comment: @123 you edited my answer and wrote that $\sup(\mathbb{Z}^-)=-1$ ; Maybe it's a difference between France and other country ? In France, $\mathbb{Z}^-$ is all negative intergers, including $0$ which is both positive and negative ; for strictly negative integers we would use $\mathbb{Z}^{-\star}$ or $\mathbb{Z}^\star_-$.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard convention on the matter, so when you write something like $\mathbb{Z}^-$ you should specify what you mean. You specifically said that it means the set of all negative integers and you didn't include zero. @hdci